# Has the nativescript sidekick discontinue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

Whenever I clicked the nativeScript sidekick download link for window it redirect me to the main page. I don't see any download link for nativescript sidekick there. So I look for the information about whether sidekick is discontinue or not but I found nothing. If someone have download link for nativescript sidekick or information about discontinuing pls share thank you

Comment: No it cannot discontinue. I think it's a problem with site maintenance team. refer this https://github.com/ProgressNS/sidekick-feedback/issues/489

Comment: Adding to @naanu, the direct link for downloading sidekick is  https://github.com/ProgressNS/sidekick-docs/wiki/Installation

Comment: Sidekick is available for local builds only, all of the cloud functionality was stripped from it https://twitter.com/bundyo/status/1269678563680280576

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be related to the fact that Progress is giving all Nativescript ecosystem to [nStudio](https://nstudio.io/)

for maintaining and further develop it.

I guess some links will change soon abd the docs will get updated.

Reference: [Official blog post](https://nativescript.org/blog/the-next-chapter-for-nativescript-nstudio/)

Comment: For further readers, from the guy involved in this tool creation, https://twitter.com/bundyo/status/1269678563680280576

Answer (score 0):

A day later... now the download links are working, it seems Sidekick stays with Progress.

Comment: the latest info about this subject points to Sidekick being left to its owner (Progress, which will not maintain it anymore) while the new NS maintainer, nStudio, will work on a cloud build solution which will be ready when it is ready. Meanwhile you are advised to use this, https://nativescript.org/blog/migration-of-nativescript-cloud-builds-to-circle-ci/

Answer (score 0):

> its removed from nativescript to gave the responsibility to
> [nstudo](https://nstudio.io/)
>
> nativescript-sidekick is avalaible for local download visit this link. i have downloaded from this link
>
> https://github.com/ProgressNS/sidekick-docs/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 23, 2023. It is now read-only.